# How to specify list item count in preview of recyclerview in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-tools-namespace

The recyclerview layout is defined as

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/call_detail_list"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:listitem="@layout/call_item"
            />
```

In the preview, I can see the list items from the specified layout,
but the number of item is 10. Is there any way that can be changed?

Comment: I have been looking into this as well without success. There's nothing specified in the documentation. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html#design-time_view_attributes

Comment: You should accept the answer from @Diego Alejandro about setting `tools:itemCount="3"`.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Try this (3 number of items)

`tools:itemCount="3"`

Comment: This worked for me on Android 3.0 but NOT on Android 2.3.

Comment: This is correct, however it won't work if you also have the `tools:listitem` property defined

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way to do it but you can limit the `layout_height` here so that it only shows enough items that fits within the height/width boundary. So play around with `tools:layout_height="150dp"`

Comment: I tried this, but it seems that the tools:listitem argument overrides the layout height... For me the 10 list items still show up.